# AngularJS multiple Scope needed for Autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I have an array structure like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "city": "NY"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Gerold",
    "city": "LA"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Stuart",
    "city": "Boston"
  }  
]
```

I need **$scope** like below for my autocomplete search.

```
$scope.name=["john","Gerold","Stuart"];
$scope.city=["NY","LA","Boston"];
```

can anyone help to get this using angularjs controller.
Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MAP..

```
$scope.YourBigArray = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "city": "NY"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Gerold",
  "city": "LA"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Stuart",
  "city": "Boston"
}];

$scope.names = $scope.YourBigArray.map(function(object) {
  return object.name;
});
$scope.cities = $scope.YourBigArray.map(function(object) {
  return object.city;
});
```

You can do a filter to use unique things in array of names and cities..

```
function filterForDuplicate(things) {
  return things.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return things.indexOf(item) === pos;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rakeschand ..! I'll try this..!!

Answer (score 1):

Use MAP

```
$scope.users = [
  {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "city": "NY"
  },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Gerold",
  "city": "LA"
 },
 {
   "id": "3",
  "name": "Stuart",
  "city": "Boston"
 }  
];

$scope.cities = $scope.users.map(function(obj){ 

 return obj.city;
});

console.log($scope.cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a helper function that would do that for you and you don't have to define a map per function that you want, and you do it in just one run (hence just a bit faster)

Sample here ;)

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "city": "NY"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Gerold",
        "city": "LA"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Stuart",
        "city": "Boston"
    }
]
function toScope(scopedPropertieNames, array) {
    scopedPropertieNames.forEach(function(propertyName) {
        if (! $scope[propertyName]) {
            $scope[propertyName] = []
        }
    });
    array.forEach(function (objecInArray) {
        scopedPropertieNames.forEach(function(propertyName) {
            $scope[propertyName].push(objecInArray[propertyName])
        })
    });
}

toScope(['name', 'city'], myArray);
console.log($scope) //{name: Array[3], city: Array[3]}
```